# Printing file name containing underscore

Tags: math-mode, pdfpages, text-mode

I am using `pdfpages` package to include a few files into the big one. I want to print the file name, go to new page and include the file. The problem is that when the filename contains `_` LaTeX yelds `missing $ inserted` (because the `_` is allowed in math-mode only, I guess). How can I deal with it?

Using sth like `\def_\_` didn't help. I also tried some of the solutions from this site, but didn't get any result.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand{\INC}[1]{%
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    \large #1
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,doublepages=true,landscape,frame=true]{#1}
}


\begin{document}
\INC{file_name.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\large\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\detokenize`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand{\INC}[1]{%
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    \large\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,doublepages=true,landscape,frame=true]{#1}
}


\begin{document}
\INC{file_name.pdf}
\end{document}
```

If you want to use the text font, remove `\ttfamily` and add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble.

Alternate approach (suggested by daleif): use `url`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages,url}

\DeclareUrlCommand{\filename}{\urlstyle{rm}}% or \urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\INC}[1]{%
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    \large\filename{#1}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,doublepages=true,landscape,frame=true]{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\INC{file_name.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would `\path` from URL be better if the names are long? (just wondering)

Comment: @daleif Good suggestion!

Comment: Thx, I really like the `url` approach.

Answer (score 2):

egreg has already given an answer which is probably better. But since you have mentioned it in your question I would like to add a few words on redefining `_`.

In TeX each character has a [catcode (category code)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode). `_` has by default catcode 8 (subscript). With `\def` one can define

- control sequences (starting with an escape character and consisting of one or more letter characters)
- control characters (starting with an escape character and consisting of exactly one non-letter character)
- active characters (exactly one character of catcode 13, without an escape character)

(By the way, spaces are gobbled after control sequences only, not after control characters or active characters.)

Therefore if you want to redefine `_` you first need to make it active:

```
\catcode`_=\active
\def_{\_}
```

However one would not want to change the catcode globally because then `_` might (depending on it's definition) cause a lot of trouble else where for example in math mode when one wants to use a subscript.

When TeX reads a character for the first time it creates a token consisting of the character code and the category code. The category code of a token can *not* be changed later on. One can define a macro which changes the catcode, then calls another macro which reads some arguments and then changes the catcode back. If one were to try changing the catcode inside of the "real" macro that would be too late because then the arguments would have been read in and converted to tokens already.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% save the orginial _ for \includepdf
\def\originalunderscore{_}

\makeatletter
% make _ active so that I can use \def_ in the replacement text
\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand{\INC}{%
    % start a new group to keep catcode changes local
    \begingroup
        % change catcode of _ to active in argument of \@doINC (this does not affect the catcode of _ in the replacement text of \@doINC because that is fixed when it is defined, not when it is used)
        \catcode`_=\active
        \@doINC
}
\newcommand{\@doINC}[1]{%
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{center}
            \def_{\_}%
            \large #1%
        \end{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \newpage
        \def_{\originalunderscore}%
        \includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,doublepages=true,landscape,frame=true]{#1}
    % I am closing the group at the end instead of at the beginning to keep redefinitions of _ local (this makes no difference for the catcodes because they are fixed by the time this code is executed.)
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\catcode`_=8

\begin{document}
    \INC{file_name.pdf}
    $q_0$
\end{document}
```

Please note that this macro can not be used as an argument to another macro because it could not change the catcodes anymore.

`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` change the catcode of `@` - that is LaTeX's way of defining private macros.

But there is no need redefine `_`. Changing the catcode to other makes things easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\INC}{%
    % start a new group to keep catcode changes local
    \begingroup
        % change catcode of _ to other in argument of \@doINC
        \catcode`_=12\relax
        \@doINC
}
\newcommand{\@doINC}[1]{%
    \endgroup
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        \texttt{\large #1}%
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage
    \includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,doublepages=true,landscape,frame=true]{#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \INC{file_name.pdf}
    $q_0$
\end{document}
```

For historical reasons TeX's default font does *not* have a `_` symbol where "normal" fonts have it. Therefore it is necessary to change the font with this approach. In this example I have changed it to a typewriter font.
If you are using the following packages - which I would recommend for *german* documents - that is not necessary.

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}% neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Ermöglicht direkte Eingabe von Umlauten.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% Ermöglicht Silbentrennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten, Kopieren von Umlauten und Verwendung von Sonderzeichen wie <, >, |.
\usepackage{lmodern}% Ändert Schriftart weil die Standardschrift von T1 unschön ist und Ligaturen nicht kopiert werden könnten.
```

I have changed the catcode to other instead of letter because that does not change the allowed characters for control sequences. Otherwise if you had a `_` directly following a control sequence it would suddenly become part of the control sequence name which is most likely not what one would want.